# How to use a class to store variables that are updated in different functions, and then call these updated variables in different functions?

Tags: python, class, matrix

I am solving a problem which involves **traversing** a `n x m matrix` in a **zigzag fashion**, where `n and m` can be same number or different numbers, i.e. we will have a **square or rectangular matrix**.

To solve this problem, I have a **main method** which will traverse the matrix; and within this main method, **I create and call** on `moveDiagonallyUpwards` and `moveDiagonallyDownwards` methods to move in the zigzag way.

The problem I am having is that when I pass `row` and `col` as arguments from the main method into these two other methods, and inside these methods I update row and col, e.g. +=1 or -= 1.
These changes DO NOT reflect in the main method, when I return to the main method. And I do understand why this is the case.

So my challenge is, how can I pass back the updated `row` and `col` to the main method? I thought of using a `global class` to achieve the above.
My idea is to create a separate class to hold these variables like the below, but I am having problems with calling and using these `global row and col` in my **main method**.

Any ideas how to adjust the `row and col` in **main method** to achieve the above? Thanks!

```
array = [
    [1, 3, 4, 10],
    [2, 5, 9, 11],
    [6, 8, 12, 15],
    [7, 13, 14, 16]
  ]

class matrixMovement: 
    def __init__(self,row=0,col=0,output=[]): 
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.output = output
#Main Method
def zigzagTraverse(array):
    output.append(array[row][col])
    while array.row<= len(array)-1 or array.col<= len(array[0])-1: 
        if array.row< len(array)-1: 
            array.row += 1
            output.append(array[row][col])
            diagonalUp(row,col,array,output)
        if col < len(array[0])-1: 
            col += 1
            output.append(array[row][col])
            diagonalDown(row,col,array,output)
    return output
            
def diagonalUp(row,col,array,output): 
    while row > 0 and col< len(array[0])-1: 
        row -= 1
        col += 1
        output.append(array[row][col])
    return matrixMovemenet(row,col,output)
    
def diagonalDown(row,col,array,output): 
    while row<len(array)-1 and col > 0: 
        col-= 1
        row += 1
        output.append(array[row][col])
    return matrixMovemenet(row,col,output)
```

Comment: What is `array` that is being passed to `zigzagTraverse`?

Comment: Let me add to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. One is local scope. Another is using the `return` statement but doing nothing with the object returned.

There are a few ways to solve this. One is to ignore the local variables and just create an object from `matrixMovement` and utilize the fact that it's mutable.

```
class MatrixMovement: 
    def __init__(self, row=0, col=0, output=None):
        # I modified this to avoid the mutable default
        if output is None:
            output = []
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.output = output


# Main Method
def zigzag_traverse(array):
    # this is the object we will be mutating
    obj = MatrixMovement()
    obj.output.append(array[obj.row][obj.col])
    while obj.row <= len(array) - 1 or obj.col <= len(array[0]) - 1: 
        if obj.row < len(array) - 1: 
            obj.row += 1
            obj.output.append(array[obj.row][obj.col])
            diagonal_up(obj, array)
        if obj.col < len(array[0]) - 1: 
            obj.col += 1
            obj.output.append(array[obj.row][obj.col])
            diagonal_down(obj, array)
        # without this condition the loop will never break
        if obj.row == len(array) - 1 and obj.col == len(array[0]) - 1:
            break
    return obj.output


def diagonal_up(obj, array):
    # since we are passing in a mutable object
    # anything attribute we change on it
    # will be reflected on the object from the call site
    while obj.row > 0 and obj.col < len(array[0]) - 1: 
        obj.row -= 1
        obj.col += 1
        obj.output.append(array[obj.row][obj.col])


def diagonal_down(obj, array):
    # the same rules as diagonal_up
    while obj.row < len(array) - 1 and obj.col > 0: 
        obj.col -= 1
        obj.row += 1
        obj.output.append(array[obj.row][obj.col])
```

Comment: It's so neat! This is kind of how I thought about doing it, but I was thinking how to write matrixMovement like a million times throughout the code, so when you do obj= matrixMovement; this is so helpful! - as I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: I was aware of the referencing too, I see how you referenced obj. everything, which makes. Can I ask- why did you do an if statement when initialising the output? can I not initialize it as output = [] in the argument?

Comment: You can but if you call it with no arguments it will use the same `[]` for every subsequent call. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument/11416002) for a better explanation.

Comment: I should mention I didn't actually test if the base code itself has a bug. I just changed it to behave the way you expected yours to.

Comment: Okay, to make sure I understand it right from the link, by doing output = [] will be an issue- as stated in the link- only when we call it with no arguments? Otherwise it is fine?

Comment: @Patrick_Chong that is correct. It's best to just leave it out or set it to something like `None` so users of the function don't assume that they can call it without arguments.

Comment: thanks for confirming @Axe319. One other thing- I am now debugging the code, and I noticed that when the debugger runs over obj.row or obj.col ; I am presented with a MatrixMovement object- is there anyway I can turn this into integer for the purpose of debugging? - As it's hard to tell where the issue is without this!

Answer (score -2):

I chose to write this code with documentation, boundary checks, and after solving a few bugs I found in your traversal.

Explanation is written in comments. You're welcome to ask if there's anything you don't understand.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence, TypeAlias

from dataclasses import dataclass

_T = TypeVar("_T")

MatrixType = Sequence[Sequence[_T]]

@dataclass
class Point:
    row: int
    col: int

def zigzag_traverse(matrix: MatrixType[_T]) -> list[_T]:
    output: list[_T] = []

    row_length = len(matrix[0])
    if any(len(row) != row_length for row in matrix):
        raise ValueError("Matrix is not rectangular.")
    
    # Initialize.
    boundry = Point(len(matrix) - 1, row_length - 1)
    
    if boundry.row < 0 or boundry.col < 0:
        return output  # Matrix is empty.

    pointer = Point(0, 0)


    # Start traversing.

    output.append(matrix[pointer.row][pointer.col])
    
    
    while pointer != boundry:

        # Go right until edge, then start moving down.
        if pointer.col < boundry.col:
            pointer.col += 1
        else:
            pointer.row += 1

        output.extend(_diagonal_left_down(pointer, matrix))

        # We reached the boundry, stop traversing.
        if pointer == boundry:
            break

        # Go down until edge, then start moving right.
        if pointer.row < boundry.row:
            pointer.row += 1
        else:
            pointer.col += 1

        output.extend(_diagonal_right_up(pointer, matrix))
    
    return output

def _diagonal_left_down(pointer: Point, matrix: MatrixType[_T]) -> list[_T]:
    """Traverse left-down diagonal.
    
    Args:
        pointer: The current position. Will be modified.
        matrix: The matrix to move over.
    
    Returns:
        The list of elements traversed.
    """
    row, col = pointer.row, pointer.col
    output = []

    while row < len(matrix) - 1 and col > 0:
        output.append(matrix[row][col])
        row += 1
        col -= 1
    
    # Reached the edge
    output.append(matrix[row][col])
    pointer.row, pointer.col = row, col

    return output

def _diagonal_right_up(pointer: Point, matrix: MatrixType[_T]) -> list[_T]:
    """Traverse right-up diagonal.
    
    Args:
        pointer: The current position. Will be modified.
        matrix: The matrix to move over.
    
    Returns:
        The list of elements traversed.
    """
    row, col = pointer.row, pointer.col
    output = []

    while row > 0 and col < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
        output.append(matrix[row][col])
        row -= 1
        col += 1
    
    # Reached the edge
    output.append(matrix[row][col])
    pointer.row, pointer.col = row, col

    return output
```